# CentOS 6 - Remote GDM doesn't come up automatically

Tags: centos, x11, gdmgreeting

I have a bunch of systems running different subreleases of CentOS 6, at different update levels. All of these machines have been configured to allow remote graphical sessions via GDM by adding the following settings to `/etc/gdm/custom.conf`:

```
[security]
DisallowTCP=false
AllowRemoteRoot=true

[xdmcp]
Enable=true

[greeter]
IncludeAll=true
```

And then changing the default runlevel to 5 in `/etc/inittab`:

```
id:5:initdefault:
```

Everything runs fine on all the systems but one. On one machine, running CentOS 6.7, despite being configured as the other ones (as far as I can tell), remote GDM sessions aren't available after reboot. Among this machine's processes I see

```
root      2295  2277  1 13:24 tty6     00:00:00 /usr/bin/Xorg :9 -ac -nolisten tcp vt6 -br
```

I found that from this stage I can make remote sessions available by issuing

```
kill -1 2295
```

After that the `Xorg` command line changes to:

```
/usr/bin/Xorg :0 -br -verbose -audit 4 -auth /var/run/gdm/auth-for-gdm-AwWtUF/database vt1
```

And everything works as expected.

Does anybody have an idea about why this is happening and how can I fix it? Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like X is starting before your remote GDM.  What about runlevel 3?

Comment: I'll try switching as soon as I have the machine to myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was caused by the fact that the firstboot service was still enabled on these machines. After executing `chkconfig firstboot off` and rebooting the runlevel 5 startup took place correctly.